# How to predict the next variable in a row based on current patterns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the pets a certain owner bought in chronological order. I would like to predict which pet an owner is likely to purchase next by identifying how often one type of pet follows another (ex. Buys Dog, and then buys Cat). How do I identify the count of each permutation?

```
df <- data.frame(
id = c("AZ001", "AZ002", "AZ003", "AZ004", "AZ005"),
p1 = c("Dog", "Cat", "Fish", "Dog", "Cat"),
p2 = c("Dog", "Fish", "Dog", "Cat", "Cat"),
p3 = c("Fish", "Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "Fish"),    
p4 = c(NA, "Cat", NA, "Fish", "Dog"),     
p5 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Cat", "Dog"))
```

Essentially, I want a table of counts of how many times one pet led to another, ie:

- Dog - Fish (1)
- Dog - Cat (1)
- Dog - Dog (3)

Comment: @MrFlick I think it's tabulation of sequences of length two (Dog+Dog then Dog+Fish on the first row), not sure though.

Comment: @MrFlick desired output added in edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a reasonable strategy would be to iteratve over the column pairs and create an interaction that you can summarize via `table()`. For example

```
animal.cols <- 2:6
as.data.frame(table(unlist(lapply(seq_along(head(animal.cols,-1)), function(i) {
    y<-df[,c(animal.cols[i], animal.cols[i+1])];
    interaction(y[[1]],y[[2]])
}))))
```

which returns

```
       Var1 Freq
1   Cat.Cat    2
2   Dog.Cat    1
3  Fish.Cat    2
4   Cat.Dog    0
5   Dog.Dog    3
6  Fish.Dog    2
7  Cat.Fish    3
8  Dog.Fish    1
9 Fish.Fish    1
```

Answer (score 5):

First, convert to character:

```
df[]   <- lapply(df,as.character)
```

Then, we can get rid of the NAs by storing in long format:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2) # not needed with data.table 1.9.5+
dflong <- setDT(na.omit(melt(df, id.var="id")))
```

Finally, using data.table syntax, we can (1) construct the pairs and (2) tabulate:

```
dflong[,
  paste(head(value,-1), tail(value,-1), sep="_")
,by=id][,
  table(V1)
]
```

The new variable constructed by `paste` is given the default name `V1`. The result is:

```
V1
  Cat_Cat  Cat_Fish   Dog_Cat   Dog_Dog  Dog_Fish  Fish_Cat  Fish_Dog Fish_Fish 
        2         3         1         3         1         2         2         1
```